# Why pig is called batch processing

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is pig a batch processing? if so, please let me know why is it called a batch processing. is it batch processing because it runs a map reduce.

Answer (score 2):

In data processing we can deal with every record separately (a timestamped record is called event) or deal with a collection of records which called a batch.

Pig perform batch processing, because it does not process input records one by one, indeed Pig loads all available records in the input path as one batch.

Map Reduce is a data processing framwork designed for batch processing, mapreduce means batch processing but batch processing is not mapreduce.

Comment: You are welcome @MrShetty, please accept the answer to make helpful.